# Git can't display UTF-8 filename correctly

Tags: git

I've change my `core.quotepath` to `off`.

My `locale` is UTF-8

I use Git Bash on Windows 10, Git Bash's text font set to be Consolas.

But my `初めに.txt` file showed up as `σê¥πéüπü½.txt`

[Font error, 初めに.txt got changed to σê¥πéüπü½.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q5qh.jpg)

[Text Font has been set to Consolas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Zlet.jpg)

```
longnx@DESKTOP-D46DU6R MINGW64 /d/tmp/demo-utf8 (master)
$ git config -l
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=false
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=true
credential.helper=manager
pull.rebase=false
merge.tool=kdiff3
mergetool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
diff.guitool=kdiff3
difftool.kdiff3.path=C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
core.editor='d:/apps/npp/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.quotepath=off
pull.rebase=false
fetch.prune=false
rebase.autostash=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
(END)
```

here is my `locale`, all UTF-8

```
longnx@DESKTOP-D46DU6R MINGW64 /d/tmp/demo-utf8 (master)
$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

here is `git status` return

```
longnx@DESKTOP-D46DU6R MINGW64 /d/tmp/demo-utf8 (master)
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        σê¥πéüπü½.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

although `ls` show it correctly

```
longnx@DESKTOP-D46DU6R MINGW64 /d/tmp/demo-utf8 (master)
$ ls
初めに.txt
```

---

Update 2020-08-31

After some tries, I all-in all my last hope on reinstalling Git for Windows, now it display correctly without any setting ¯\＿(ツ)＿/¯

Comment: Does add and commit actually work?

Comment: Yes `git add `  works well.

Comment: So there is really no problem except in how git status displays the name.

Comment: @matt : it will be matter if you have 10/15 JP files should NOT be added, and you don't know "what is what" :)

Comment: you can check what bytes are issued on the stdout of the commands : compare `ls | hd` and `git status -s | hd` (I assume that `git status -s` has the same display bug as `git status`)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP mentions the bug disappeared and is not able to reproduce it anymore.